# how to normalize or decode an URL in python?

Tags: python, url

I have a link like below

```
http%253A%252F.....25252520.doc
```

How do i convert this to normal link in python?..the link has lots of encoded stuff..

Comment: Just saw the answer on other question..

Answer (score 4):

for python3.5+ Apply `urllib.parse.unquote` twice:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> strs = urllib.parse.unquote("http%253A%252F.....25252520.doc")
>>> urllib.parse.unquote(strs)
'http:/.....25252520.doc'
```

In older versions of Python apply [`urllib.unquote`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) twice:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> strs = urllib.unquote("http%253A%252F.....25252520.doc")
>>> urllib.unquote(strs)
'http:/.....25252520.doc'
```

Comment: And `urllib.parse.unquote` for python3.5+
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote

Answer (score 2):

Use [`urllib.unquote()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote):

> Replace `%xx` escapes by their single-character equivalent.

It *looks* as if you have a double or ever triple encoded URL; the `http://` part has been encoded to `http%253A%252F` which decodes to `http%3A%2F` which in turn becomes `http:/`. The URL itself may contain another stage of encoding but you didn't share enough of the actual URL with us to determine that.

Comment: Although in OP's example, you have to unquote it _twice_. First, all those `%25` are unquoted to `%`, then the actual unquoting is done.